# How to get value of radio button for every select option in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

hello i have a problem related to radio button value.first of all take a look at array structure

```
Array
(
[spe_lan] => Array
    (
        [0] => Russian
        [1] => Hebrew
        [2] => Tamil
        [3] => Vietnamese
    )

[spoken] => Array
    (
        [0] => No
        [1] => Yes
        [2] => Yes
        [3] => Yes
    )

[written] => Array
    (
        [0] => No
        [1] => Yes
        [2] => Yes
        [3] => Yes
    )

[set_priamy] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[Submit] => Save
[modified] => 2016-06-03 10:02:14
 )
```

in this array i select 4 languages but only one is primary language so how i get language name which is primary.
i use select box with name taken in array and radio button name also taken in array.please simplyfy this how i implement
also i use appendTo to add more languages on click please simplify 
here is my html code

```
                         <form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->webroot?>Jobseeker/add_language" id="add_skills">
                    <div class="ex-form-edit2" style="display:none;" id="yerte">
                    <div class="add-skils-form2">
                    <div class="skill-a-lan">
                    <h4>Languages <span>*</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="skill-spo">
                    <h4>Spoken <span>*</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="skill-wri">
                    <h4>Written <span>*</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="skill-primari">
                    <h4>Primary <span>*</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="appendbox">
                    <div class="add-skils-form">
                    <div class="skill-a-lan">
                    <select  class="defualt-select default-size" name="spe_lan[]" required>
                    <option value="" >Select</option>
                    <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
                    <option value="Bahasa Indonesia">Bahasa Indonesia</option>
                    <option value="Bahasa Malaysia">Bahasa Malaysia</option>
                    <option value="Bengali">Bengali</option>
                    <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
                    <option value="Dutch">Dutch</option>
                    <option value="English">English</option>
                    <option value="Filipino">Filipino</option>
                    <option value="French">French</option>
                    <option value="German">German</option>
                    <option value="Hebrew">Hebrew</option>
                    <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
                    <option value="Italian">Italian</option>
                    <option value="Japanese">Japanese</option>
                    <option value="Korean">Korean</option>
                    <option value="Portuguese">Portuguese</option>
                    <option value="Russian">Russian</option>
                    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                    <option value="Tamil">Tamil</option>
                    <option value="Thai">Thai</option>
                    <option value="Vietnamese">Vietnamese</option>


                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="skill-spo">
                    <select class="defualt-select default-size" name="spoken[]">
                    <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
                    <option value="No" >No</option>


                    </select>

                    </div>
                    <div class="skill-wri">
                    <select  class="defualt-select default-size" name="written[]">
                    <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
                    <option value="No" >No</option>

                    </select>

                    </div>
                    <div class="skill-primari">
                    <input type="radio" value="1" name="set_priamy[]" onclick="getvalue();"/>
                    <a href="#" class="delete-row"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>



                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="add-skill-row"><span><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Language</span></div>
                    <div class="ex-form2-row">
                    <div class="ex-form-field"><input type="submit" value="Save" name="Submit" class="button-default">
                    <a id="btn_cancel3" name="btn_cancel" href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" onclick="ddggjdg();">Cancel</a></div>
                    </div>

                    </div></form>
```

Comment: Do you have tired any html code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want get selected value of a radio button in PHP here the code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 1">Radio 1
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 2">Radio 2
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 3">Radio 3
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(isset($_POST['radio']))
{
echo "You have selected :".$_POST['radio'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
}
?>
```